# Tough Differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can anyone help me solve this question ?

$$ \large{y^{\prime \prime} + y = \tan{t} + e^{3t} -1}$$
I have gotten to a part when I know $r = \pm 1$ and then plugging them into a simple differential equation. I do not know how to the next step.

Thank you very much for all your help.

Comment: Can you show how did you get to the part where $r =\pm 1$

Comment: y'' + y = 0  The initial step. since r^2 + 1 = 0 --> r = ±1i.

Comment: There is an entirely automatized approach to solve these differential equations. Was it not explained to you?

Comment: I'm suppose to use method of coefficient. But i'm not too sure how to approach it after i got yc. since General solution is y = yc + yp. Im not too sure how to find  yp in the certain question.

Comment: Would this question be easier if I choose to use Variation of Parameter?

Comment: I agree that the $\tan t$ makes it a bit difficult (depending on method) to find the particular solution. What are your tools?

Comment: I'm  allowed to use either of the methods. But I just learned variation of parameters so i was feeling shaky about it.

Comment: Oh, so you were given a systematic method but you ask the question here to *avoid* applying the method yourself? Since the exercise is meant to make you apply the method, this seems like a pretty sure way to *avoid* learning the subject (and, ultimately, a sure way to fail the exam, if an exam is approaching). Maths is not a spectator's sport, one can only learn it by doing things oneself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the complementary solution by solving
\begin{equation*}
y''+y=0.
\end{equation*}
Substitute $y=e^{\lambda t}$ to get 
\begin{equation*}
(\lambda ^2+1)e^{\lambda t}=0.
\end{equation*}
Therefore the zeros are $\lambda=i$ or $\lambda =-i.$ The general solution is given by 
\begin{equation*}
y=y_1+y_2=c_1e^{it}+\frac{c_2}{e^{it}}.
\end{equation*}
Apply Euler's identity and regroup the terms to get 
\begin{equation*}
y=(c_1+c_2)\cos(t)+i(c_1-c_2)\sin(t) \\
=c_3\cos(t)+c_2\sin(t).
\end{equation*}
For the particular solution, try $y_{b_1}=\cos(t)$ and $y_{b_2}=\sin(t).$ Calculating the Wronskian $W$ gives $1$. Let $f(t)$ be RHS of the differential equation. Use the two formulae
\begin{equation*}
v_1=-\int \frac{f(t)y_{b_2}}{W},~v_2=\int \frac{f(t)y_{b_1}}{W}
\end{equation*}
to get the particular solution
\begin{equation*}
y_p=v_1y_{b_1}+v_2y_{b_2}.
\end{equation*}